# SPF,DKIM Failure and outcome

Tags: email, spf, dkim, dmarc

I have been doing a lot of reading around SPF, DKIM and DMARC and i think i have digested most of the information and how all three work in the email world. However one question i couldn't find is, What will happen to an email if SPF failed and DKIM passed and vice versa? Will that email be delivered normally?

I have setup DMARC for our domain and within the reports i'm seeing some emails from google/yahoo etc passing SPF and failing DKIM and vice versa, does this mean the emails are getting delivered?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

DMARC compliance requires that one of SPF and/or DKIM pass both SPF/DKIM authentication AND DMARC alignment tests.

So long as EITHER SPF or DKIM is both authenticated and aligned, the message will pass DMARC tests and be delivered to the recipient inbox.

Should BOTH SPF and DKIM fail alignment, DMARC will fail and the sender DMARC policy will apply (p=none | p=quarantine | p=reject).

DMARC policy is the recommendation of the sending domain as to how the recipient mail agent SHOULD treat the message if it fails *both* SPF and DKIM alignment (e.g. deliver to 'Junk mail' or quarantine, or potentially outright reject the message).

Requiring that only one of SPF or DKIM pass DMARC alignment tests provides a bit of a 'failsafe' for properly authenticated messages. For example, messages forwarded through a compliant server add an Authenticated Received Chain (ARC) header to preserve the original DKIM signature validation; a valid DKIM ARC signature will allow the forwarded message to pass DKIM DMARC alignment tests and be delivered to the ultimate recipient inbox despite being forwarded through one or more intermediate servers.

Comment: Methinks it's the other way round: forwarded messages fail dkim (content is changed) but not spf (does not care about content, only envelope).

Comment: Edited to include clarification; intermediate mail servers insert ARC headers to allow a message passing through multiple servers to pass DMARC despite failing SPF alignment.